# How to change Startup File default value on Azure App Service when deploying from VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I accidentally input wrong **Startup File** path when first time configuring deployment from VSTS. Now every time when a new release is deployed by VSTS, the value is always changed back to the original incorrect one. How do I fix the issue?

[image: Startup File]

Comment: The screenshot was taken from Application Settings -> Runtime after deployment from VSTS is configured. The value will be overridden every release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

1. Go to (Your Project) -> Release -> (Your Release Definition) -> Edit.
2. Go to Tasks -> Deploy Azure App Service.

Change **Startup command** field and save.

[image]
[image]